# How do I set values for a possibly incalculable member of a class?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a Matrix class in C++ 17. I've just completed the implementation of the calculation of determinants. However, this is only for matrices that are 2x2 and 3x3. Is there a way I could define the member "determinant" so that it does not default to 0 or another number when it is not calculated? Is there any equivalent to NULL that won't print out to the console as 0?

Thank you!

Comment: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: Also does this question have anything to do with matrices or determinants?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/nan-function/  : "The NaN values are used to identify undefined or non-representable values for floating-point elements, such as the square root of negative numbers or the result of 0/0."  The output is not a 0 or NULL. I think it is "nan".

Comment: Well I suppose the problem itself doesn't have anything specifically to do with matrices or determinants but I included that information to add some context. @Mikhail

Comment: Thanks @2785528! I'll check that out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `std::optional<>`  It's designed specifically for cases like this where you want to have an "out of band" invalid value.

If you go this route, you'll need to explicitly test the determinant before attempting to print it, and if it has not been set, print either nothing or something like `"unset"`

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I'm looking for @dgnuff. Thanks a lot!